# Publish a standalone app on Appexchange

Tags: appexchange

I have developed a Windows based standalone application that works with Salesforce APIs. It is a utility application performing various types of operation.

Wanted to list the application on Appexchange. Gone through the below links but none of them mentions steps on how to create listing for a standalone app on AppExchange( the links just provide info on listing Apex based applications - managed applications).

Can someone please help me on how to create listing of client applications on AppExchange?

Thanks,
Vertika

Comment: Can you follow the process at the bottom of the appexchange home page: "List On The AppExchange"?

Answer (score 0):

Vertika,
I read an article that states you can specify the location to "Get It Now" as an external URL.
How did you end up publishing your application?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question.  Feel free to post a question of your own about this topic.  Once you gain a few reputation point here, you'll be able to comment on existing questions.